# simple but confusing integral derivative expression

Tags: calculus

I am trying to understand what $\frac{d}{ds} \int_s^T f(s,t) dt$ evaluates to.

For example, I know that $\frac{d}{ds} \int_s^T f(t) dt = -f(s)$ by a simply tweaking of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: tried Leibniz integral rule?

Comment: I thought of this, however, the variable $s$ appears in the limits of integration also

Comment: This is also covered by the Leibniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: ah, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks